# Terraform: How to get current action as variable

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

There is one resource which don't have pre-defined resource. So as as workaround, we preferred to used "null-resource".

Let's discuss with a example (Please don't stick with this example. Try to get the nature of requirement. Played a lot with conditional expression) -

Based on the terraform **ACTION** value (apply, destroy etc), do the below activity. Enlighten here if more inbuilt Terraform environment variables are available that can provide more flexibility in automation.

```
locals {
  action = "${TF_CLI_ARGS}" == "apply" ? "install" : ("${TF_CLI_ARGS}" == "destroy" ? "remove" : "update")
  package = "httpd"
  version = "2.4.6"
}

resource "null_resource" "test" {
  triggers = {
    action = "${local.action}"
  }

  triggers = {
    action = "${local.version}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "yum -y ${local.action} ${package}-${version}"
  }
}
```

Case 1: **Install**

Install the given package if `apply` is in command line.

Case 2: **Delete**

Uninstall the given package if `destroy` is in command line.

Case 3: **Update**

Update the given package based on delta in version number.

Comment: Nice blog about conditonal logic https://blog.boltops.com/2020/10/03/terraform-hcl-conditional-logic/

Comment: @RichardRublev Thanks but don't want to play with 2 level of activity. Logically think  just to uninstall a package,  firstly we have update the 'variable "create" to false' then apply it and then again do terraform destroy to delete the "null-resource". Core requirement is somehow to get current terraform action as varirable.

Comment: By what you are saying `"Please don't stick with this example."` I get a feeling that what you are doing is not about installing packages with yum locally ... You start with `There is one resource which don't have pre-defined resource.` what resource is that?  what terraform provider? ... Most terraform providers are Open Source, ideally you can make the changes there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform is a desired state system, so the configuration describes the system that ought to exist rather than the specific actions required to create it.

When you create a destroy-mode plan Terraform still checks that the configuration is valid but ignores most of it because destroying is primarily a state-driven operation: any object that is tracked in the state must be planned for destruction regardless of how it is configured.

However, in your particular case you are using [Provisioners](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax), which are essentially an escape hatch to tell Terraform to perform imperative actions during either the create or destroy actions of instances of a particular resource. This is a pragmatic exception to the "desired state" structure which is defining a specific action to take rather than just a declaration of what ought to exist.

Due to provisioners being an imperative escape hatch, they *do* have the ability to react to create vs. destroy, like this:

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    # create-time provisioner
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when = destroy
    # destroy-time provisioner
  }
```

With blocks like the above in any `resource` block, Terraform will execute the create-time provisioner as part of applying any "create" action for an instance of the resource, and the destroy-time provisioner as part of applying a "destroy" action for an instance of the resource. Terraform will sometimes plan to replace an object with a new equivalent object, in which case that counts as both a create and a destroy action and so both would run when applying that change.

[Provisioners are a last resort](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#provisioners-are-a-last-resort), so better to use a declarative mechanism included as part of a provider if possible, but if there's no way to achieve your goal other than provisioners then using this pairing of create-time and destroy-time provisioners is one way to make the imperative actions behave in a "resource-like" way.

Comment: suggested solution are pretty closure to the requirement. Thanks @Martin Atkins